# Calculating satellites orbits

Tags: gravity, satellites

Do Newton's and Einstein's theory of Gravity differ very much when calculating satellites orbits. If they don't, in what areas do they actually differ?

Comment: When it comes to satellites the greatest inpact of Einstein gravity is in the time-dilation of the satellites. If this is not taken into account properly, GPS satellites would we unusable after a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks, new to this site, but yeah it's pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tests_of_general_relativity&oldid=696987349#Perihelion_precession_of_Mercury